# Lowest common ancestor in networkx

Tags: generator, networkx, lowest-common-ancestor

How can I get the output of this generator? `out.next()` or `next(out)` doesn't work:

```
out=nx.tree_all_pairs_lowest_common_ancestor(G)
print(out)
<generator object tree_all_pairs_lowest_common_ancestor at 0x000002BE4EF90D48>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`nx.tree_all_pairs_lowest_common_ancestor`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/lowest_common_ancestors.html) is only aimed at working on certain graph structures, as mentioned in the docs. In the case no *root* is specified, as in your case, the function will do as follows:

> If root is not specified, find the exactly one node with in degree 0 and
>   use it. Raise an error if none are found, or more than one is. Also check
>   for any nodes with in degree larger than 1, which would imply G is not a
>   tree.

So it is likely that your function either has multiple *root* nodes, or there are none, i.e your graph is not a tree. So you can either search locally using a [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), or specify the root node of the subtree to operate on in `nx.tree_all_pairs_lowest_common_ancestor`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After I have specified root node, `next(out)` worked for me. By the way, my graph is DAG.